Classification of complex structures of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$
Riemann's theorem states that simply connected Riemann surfaces are biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ or $H$ the upper-half complex plane.
It is also easy to check that the cover of a Riemann surface is also a Riemann surface with an appropriate complex structure that comes from the projection.
Moreover it's known that $ Aut(\mathbb{C})=\{z\mapsto az+b|a\neq 0\}$, $ Aut(\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}))=\mathbb{P}GL_{2}(\mathbb{C}), Aut(H)=\{z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}:ad-bc>0;(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^{4}\}$
In class we have tried to classify the Riemann surfaces finding subgroups of their automorphisms that is properly discontinuous and has no fixed points. A quotient of the simply connected RS by this groups gives us RS where the projection on the quotient is a universal cover.
In class we have seen that the complex structure of a Torus can't come either from$\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ or from the upper-half plane My question is: what about $\mathbb{C}^{*}$? I know that it cannot come from the Riemann's sphere because the only spherical RS is the Rieman Sphere as the subgroups of $Aut(\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}))$ which have the properties above are only the trivial one. But can $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ come from the upper half plane? For the torus we have seen that this can't happen because $Aut(H)$ does not contain any copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ which is the fundamental group of the torus, but for my case this strategy doesn't seem to work.

Do you know how to construct a holomorphic covering map $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C^*$?

I do for the cylinder: by quotienting for $\mathbb{Z}$. I think for $\mathbb{C}*$ doesn't change so much. But even if I knew it I would like to exclude the hyperbolic case.

In general, you construct a holomorphic covering map by constructing a holomorphic function between two domains. "Quotiening for $\mathbb Z$" is a wrong terminology and does not do the job. But can a single surface have two holomorphic universal covers, one is the complex plane and the other, the upper half plane? You have to figure such things out in order to succeed.
